# Protocol buffer sending Packet with Header C#

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

hello i have a question about Proto buffer i sniffing packet from online Games it use Proto buffer so i tried many time to sending this packet again by proto buffer but i cant it's not give any action i make console application to get result and i found result i not complete because there is length and packet number and header not appear in result to i can send packet so there is way to send header and packet ID with proto buffer without change them

here my code :

```
 [ProtoContract]
    public class Person
    {
        //[ProtoMember(0)]
        //public string Name { get; set; }
        public ushort Length;
        public uint PacketNumer;
        [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint UID;
        [ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint X;
        [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint Y;
        [ProtoMember(4, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint TimeStamp;
        [ProtoMember(5, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint JumpStyle;
        [ProtoMember(6, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint Direction;
        [ProtoMember(7, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint FromX;
        [ProtoMember(8, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint FromY;
        [ProtoMember(9, IsRequired = true)]
        public uint MapID;

    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Person input = new Person
        {


            UID = 12786811,
            X = 430,
            Y = 405,
            TimeStamp = (uint)Environment.TickCount,
            JumpStyle = 137,
            Direction = 1,
            FromX = 427,
            FromY = 410,
            MapID = 1002



        };
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, input, PrefixStyle.Fixed32);

        Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(stream.GetBuffer()));
        Person result;
        //object output;

       result = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);

        Console.ReadLine();





    }
```

that Packet i sniffing from game :

```
2F 00 1A 27 08 FB B8 8C 06 38 BC 03 40 FC 02 48 9B C4 BF 40 60 89 01 68 07 70 BB 03 78 FA 02 88 01 CF 0F A0 01 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 01
```

Here is Result by App:

```
1E-00-00-00-08-FB-B8-8C-06-10-AE-03-18-95-03-20-A0-AB-B3-41-28-89-01-30-01-38-AB-03-40-9A-03-48-CF-0F
```

i want send packet exactly like packet i sniffing with header and packet ID in Offset 2>> 1A 27
are there is way fro that?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prefix here clearly isn't fixed-32; it might be varint (base-128), so the first change would be to use that.

Now, you mention a packet number and length. If these aren't in a suitable protobuf format, then simply: you might need to write the header manually. I know there is code to *decode* a raw varint on the public API, but I can't recall if there is code to *encode* one - but: it isn't ultimately very complex. So: worst case, write the first few bytes yourself.

Finally: never use GetBuffer() unless you're trapping the Length and limiting to it. It returns an *oversized* buffer.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply i used Base-128 Before it's just replace buffer from offset 4 to offset 2 and how i put Header manually  in proto buffer function if there is Exampel that maybe Help